# This is the code to stop zoomin of browser using controll+scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleWheel = (e) => {
      if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e);
    };
    window.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel, { passive: false });
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel, { passive: true });
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="hover">Hover me </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can someone explain me what is the roll of {passive:false} in this code
or{passive:true} in the code

Comment: See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), setting the option `passive: false` tells the browser that the handler might call `.preventDefault()` to cancel the default action for the event.
It also says that in general `passive: false` is the default, but some browsers make `passive: true` to be the default for certain events, including `'wheel'` events, so setting it to `false` is necessary for being consistent across all browsers.

As for setting `passive: true` when calling `.removeEventListener()` - I don't see a reason. By what I understand from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#matching_event_listeners_for_removal), it is supposed to be ignored completely, though on some browser releases  it might prevent the removal of the handler when it doesn't match the original options in the call to `.addEventListener()`.